# UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte when read json contains chinese

Tags: python, json, unicode, utf-8

I'm switching from Python 2 to 3

In my jupyter notebook the code is

```
file = "./data/test.json" 
with open(file) as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

It used to be fine with python 2, but now after just switch to python 3, it gives me the error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 123: illegal multibyte sequence
```

The `test.json` file is like this:

```
[{
    "name": "Daybreakers",
    "detail_url": "http://www.movieinsider.com/m4120/daybreakers/",
    "movie_tt_id": "中文"
  }]
```

If I delete the chinese, there will be no error.

So what should I do?

There are a lot of similar questions in SO, but I didn't find a good solution for my case. If you find an applicable one, please tell me and I'll close this one.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify the correct encoding when you open the file. If the JSON is encoded with UTF-8 you can do this:

```
import json

fname = "test.json" 
with open(fname, encoding='utf-8') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

print(data)
```

**output**

```
[{'name': 'Daybreakers', 'detail_url': 'http://www.movieinsider.com/m4120/daybreakers/', 'movie_tt_id': '中文'}]
```